# jQuery if var is empty hide button

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, if-statement

Currently trying to teach myself javascript/jQuery and just having a little bit of trouble at the moment i've created a internal logo repo to allow easy access to all of the logo the company requires just as a little task.

However i have a separate JSON file with all of the logo details for each set of logos' and then my problem is this:

```
  var logoType_ai = (value.logo_ai == null) ? value.logo_ai : $(".btn-ai").hide();
```

I'm trying to get it to check in the json file if the logo.ai variable is empty "" if so then hide the button else display button.

at the moment its just hiding all of the buttons on each set of logos how would i go about making this check each variable group then deciding if it should show or hide the button for that group?

```
{
  "id": "VMLM",
  "title": "Virgin Money London Marathon",
  "logo_small": "small",
  "logo_medium": "medium",
  "logo_large": "large",
  "swatch_1": "#ed363f",
  "swatch_2": "#0c4493",
  "logo_ai": "",
  "logo_eps": "",
  "logo_svg": "",
  "logo_png": ".png",
  "logo_jpg": ".jpg"
},
```

Comment: an empty string is not the same as null. if (value.logo_ai === "")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var logoType_ai = value.logo_ai;

if(logoType_ai == ''){
    $(".btn-ai").hide();
}else{
    $(".btn-ai").show(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Null is not empty. As a simple test try this:

```
var str = null
console.log(typeof(str)); // output is object; this in fact is an empty object

var str = "";
console.log(typeof(str)); // result is string;
```

You should compare with empty string:

```
var logoType_ai = (value.logo_ai === "") ? value.logo_ai : $(".btn-ai").hide();
```